# active div class and display:block

Tags: html, css

Page referenced is here: http://briansmall.com/inovar/capabilities-test.html

Trouble I'm having is in displaying a slider correctly due to "div class" being active or not.

As long as the div class is active ("Shrink Sleeves" from the left navigation), the slider appears and operates correctly (references display: block in the style sheet). If the div class isn't active ("Flexible Packaging" for example), then the slider stacks the images and the slider doesn't appear correctly - (display: none).

I'm assuming that it has to do with the display: block and display: none, but I'm stuck as to how to make each nav tab on the left display a functional slider on the right.  Single images appear fine (Pressure Sensitive Labels), it's just when I try to implement images that scroll, or slide that I get the problem.

I hope I'm making sense.  I just want a series of images (3) to scroll when their nav is selected on the left versus just being able to display one single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the cause of the problem you are encountering is IDs of the divs. **IDs supposed to be unique**. `slideContainer` , `slideShim` are specified as IDs where they should be classes instead. You should probably change other IDs which are appearing more than once in the page.

You might want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideShim').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  1500,
        timeout: 4000,
        prev:   '.back',
        next:   '.forward',
        pause:  1,
        pager:  '.pager'
    });    
});
```

Hope this helps